# How do I sort a bound column by default in a DataGrid?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a DataGrid and I want to specify that a column is sorted by default. Using the SQL sort is not working as intended, but when I click the column header it sorts exactly as intended. I just want it to do this by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about GridView you can use [GridView.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sort%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method to sort the grid programmaticaly. E.g.

```
MyGrid.Sort("MyColumn", SortDirection.Ascending)
```